# Having a middle column with auto width while using table-layout fixed

Tags: css, html-table

I've been reading several articles and questions related to the table-layout property on Stack Overflow, but I haven't found a solution that addresses my specific issue. I've been stuck on this problem for a few hours, so I'm hoping someone can guide me in the right direction.

I have a table that handles a large amount of data and is usually much wider than the container. To allow horizontal scrolling, I've set the container to overflow-x: scroll. The client has the ability to define the widths of each column. However, a new requirement has emerged: the client wants the table to automatically adjust the column widths to the minimum necessary if a width is not explicitly defined.

I've come across suggestions in various posts that recommend leaving the last column to have an automatic width. However, in my case, I need the flexibility to set any column to have an auto width.

I've considered changing the table-layout property to auto, as I believe it might be the solution. However, when I make this change, my custom components and the performance takes a bit of a hit. So I need to find a `table-layout: fixed;` solution.

Here's a small snippet that illustrates the issue. The column with ### should have an auto width, but currently, it gets hidden behind col 4 when I attempt to do so.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.container table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.container th,
.container td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <colgroup>
      <col style="width: 50px;">
      <col style="width: 300px;">
      <!-- <col style="width: 50px;"> -->
      <col style="width: auto;">
      <col style="width: 100px;">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Columna 1</th>
        <th>Columna 2</th>
        <th>###</th>
        <th>Columna 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Contenido 1</td>
        <td>Contenido 2</td>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>Contenido 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Contenido 5</td>
        <td>Contenido 6</td>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>Contenido 8</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Let's be clear, you want to decrease the size of the second column right? I have just pasted your code in online editor and it's showing the ### column

Comment: No the widths defined are okay.
Container (400px width scroll) Col 1 (50px), Col 2 (300px) and Col 4 (100px). 
I need Col 3 (###) to be width: auto or something similar.

Col 3 it's not showing right now since width: auto is not working.

Comment: Check my comment for the solution

Comment: You might research "responsive table css" here

Answer (score 1):

`table-layout: auto;` - correct direction of thoughts. And in order to set a specific width for the cells, set them simultaneously `min-width` and `max-width`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 0;
  min-width: var(--width);
  max-width: var(--width);
}

td:nth-child(1) {
  --width: 50px;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  --width: 300px;
}

td:nth-child(3) {
  --width: unset;
}

td:nth-child(4) {
  --width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Columna 1</td>
        <td>Columna 2</td>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>Columna 4</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Contenido 1</td>
        <td>Contenido 2</td>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>Contenido 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Contenido 5</td>
        <td>Contenido 6</td>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>Contenido 8</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this could be an answer for my initial question, but I just realized that table-layout: auto; makes things a bit wonky with my custom components in my actual table. So I need to find a fixed solution it seems.

Answer (score -1):

So all you need to do is changing the required columns width to auto `<col style="auto;">` and adding a class to ### elements `<td class="hash">###</td>` and as by CSS side you need to change the CSS code to:

```
.container th,
.container td:not(.hash) {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

So it will hide all other fields but those that contains hash class

[Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/cv23b8mq/11/)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this is not what I need. The column widths have been lost in the solution you provided. The second column no longer has the specified width, and the table is adjusting to the 400px width of the container instead of having an overflow. However, I think your idea of removing the overflow: hidden from the third column might be related to the solution.

Comment: Check this, i have already updated the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/hkxfnbo5/4/), mistakenly i have changed the width of second column and forgot to change it back as before

Comment: oh min-width is a nice idea but it doesn't work for columns bigger than what's defined. Col 1 is 83px now and lost the ellipsis, max-width ain't helping too.

Comment: Consider including the solution as a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) in addition to or instead of a link to JSFiddle. We like to have answers that contain all of the code necessary to reproduce the solution, to complement questions having all of the code necessary to reproduce to issue.